# App.js:31 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from weather api and it's giving me error
my code is as follows

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      data : [],
    };
   // this.getWeather();
    this.getWeather();
  }
  
  getWeather =async()=>{
    const url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=toronto&appid='+apiKey;
    
    let req = await fetch(url);
    let res = await req.json();
}
```

[image: click here to see what error i am getting]

Comment: look in the network tab, your request is actually returning HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urls need to start with `http://` or `https://`. If you omit it, your browser will assume you intended to open a path named `api.openweathermap.org/etc/etc` on your current domain.